# A(int x=0) : x{x} {cout<<"......"<<endl;}. where is a constructor of class A and x is private variable

Tags: c++

Somewhere in a blog  I saw this line:

```
class A{
    private:
       int x;
       
       A(int x=0): x{x} {cout<<"hello";}
};
```

can anyone please clear what this line means:

```
(int x=0) : x{x}
```

with the constructor.

Comment: Read about default argument values and the constructor's initializer list in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: i think it isnt mentioned in the dupe, the member initializer list is a place where shadowing does not happen. In `x{x}` there is no ambiguity and the first `x` denotes the member, while the second `x` denotes the constructor parameter, though it is important to understand that there are two `x`  in your code

Comment: `int x=0` is a parameter named `x`, that if the callsite omits providing an argument the 0 is used at the callsite.  (This convenience has the ramification of a tighter dependency between callsite and the implementation.  May be inappropriate for larger projects and SDKs.)  the `x{x}` initializes the member variable `x` with the parameter `x`; some consider this same-name practice a bad one or at least worth discouraging (it's not ambiguous in the language, but it may cause some misunderstanding by the maintainer).